# Iterating tests robot framework

Tags: robotframework, appium-android

How to run Test suite multiple times in robot framework?

Tried using for-loop and Repeat Keyword but both didn't help out , could I get exact solution of how to iterate a test suite in robot framework.

Answer (score 4):

Robot has nothing to support this. You will need to write your own script which calls robot periodically over the 12 hour period. You can use the `--outputdir` option to have each run write to a unique output folder, and when the test run is finished you can combine all the reports into one big report with rebot.

Another solution would be to leverage a continuous integration tool such as jenkins or teamcity to automatically schedule runs over a period of time.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out and get back if I get struck anywhere.\

Answer (score 2):

You can use looping concept for this Iterating tests robot framework
this code worked for me try this

```
 *** Settings ***
         Documentation  
         Library  Selenium2Library

 *** Variables ***
         @{HOMEPAGES}    https://www.google.com  https://www.google.com
         ${Browser}  Chrome

 *** Test Cases ***
 testing with several links
         :FOR    ${homepage}     IN      @{HOMEPAGES}
         \  Funtionality  ${homepage}

 *** Keywords ***
         Funtionality
         [Arguments]  ${homepage}
         Open Browser     ${homepage}    ${Browser}

         Add all functionality which ever you need to perform
```

In the above code, I used Funtionality as a keyword and it will consider as one loop and runs, give the result

Answer (score 1):

You could use continuous integration, not sure why you would run the *suite* multiple times,
another thing is you could 
`robot tests/suite.robot tests/suite.robot ...` which would result in your *suite* running twice or more times for example

Comment: i need to run same test suite upto 12hours, if i give like this in command line it will be very big and also every time output file will be replaced. please suggest some way like if i want to run for 60times. Thanks

Comment: suggest some site to use continuous integration or some syntax how to do

Comment: you could try merging your outputs using --merge flag, so they would not be replaced, there is another possibility to output a new log and give it a number so they wouldn't overwrite the previous ones, but I can't find it in the documentation (it is definitely there)
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id642


For continuous integration, you could use Jenkins, Circle CI or Travis CI

Comment: k thankyou, i will check it out with jenkins, if there is any issue i will get back to you